# Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model on new development machine

Tags: ios, xcode, nspersistentstore

I have just set up a new machine for development using Xcode, and when I open up, build and run an existing core data project (which still works perfectly on my old machine), I receive a "Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model" error.

I have read through the myriad of questions on stackoverflow relating to this error, and thanks to them feel I have a better understanding of how iOS handles the database object model, and as far as I can tell, there is nothing obviously amiss.

I am using the standard initialisation method for my managed object model, namely...

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"project" withExtension:@"momd"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

...which is returning a nice NSManagedObjectModel on my old machine, but nil on my new one.

The bundle being compiled does contain a project.momd folder, which in turn contains a project.mom file, which is exactly the same as the compiled output on my old machine, yet one runs and one doesn't! Very frustrating!

The only thing I can think of is that there are configuration options within Xcode that I do not have set correctly on the new machine, but any help or advice would be very much appreciated!

*** UPDATE ***

The bundle on my new machine contains a project.mom inside of Project.momd. On my old machine, Project.mom is inside of Project.momd and I'm guessing the model name is case sensitive so I just need to decipher why xcode is compiling the mom in lower case...

Manually renaming project.mom to Project.mom inside the bundle does indeed fix the problem, albeit temporarily until the project is recompiled.

Comment: If you do a clean all (cmd+shift+option+k) on your old machine, and then rebuild, does your app still work? If not, your model might not be copied during the “Copy Bundle Resources” phase of your build (and your old machine may just have used a cached version).

Comment: Hi Raphael, thank you for replying. Firstly, I daren't do anything to jeopardise the currently operational status of my old machine right now as I'm currently right in the thick of a project, however the app does compile and run on various devices fine. The project.xcdatamodeld file is NOT currently included in the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase of the build, however including it does not make any difference. Is this the only file that needs to be included? Thanks again, Harry

Comment: I think I was wrong about it having to be included in that list. It does, however, have to be an active member in the target you’re trying to build. When you click on the model and open the File inspector (cmd+option+1), is there a checkmark next to your target in the “Target Membership” section?

Comment: I think I’ve figured it out: The model belongs into the “Compile Sources” section (which adding it to the target should do automatically).

Comment: There is NO checkmark next to the target in the "Target Membership" section on either the project.xcdatamodeld or the project.xcdatamodel within it. However, checking them does not seem to take as clicking away and then clicking back, the checkmark has been removed, and checking this box then building still produces the same result, so I'm guessing the membership isn't taking hold...

Comment: The project.xcdatamodeld file has been included in the compile sources all along (although Target Membership remains unchecked), and the project.momd 'folder' (containing project.mom) is being created in the compiled bundle.

Comment: Removing and re-adding project.xcdatamodeld to "Compile Sources" now sees the "Target Membership" checkbox permanently checked, however error still persists. As the project.momd NSURL is valid, i'm starting to think that "initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL" is failing to pick up the project.mom within it...

Comment: You may need to remove your app from the device or simulator in addition to cleaning before running again.

Comment: Apologies for the comment-fest, and a big thank you to you Raphael for your help, but I think I have found the reddest of Herrings. The bundle on my new machine contains a project.mom inside of Project.momd. On my old machine, Project.mom is inside of Project.momd  and I'm guessing the model name is case sensitive so I just need to decipher why xcode is compiling the mom in lower case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your xcdatamodeld “Folder” (using “Show Package Contents” in the Finder) to see if the xcdatamodel file(s) has the same case. In theory, the `xcdatamodeld` gets compiled to `momd` and `xcdatamodel` to `mom`.

Note that the iOS filesystem is case-sensitive while OSX’s isn’t (at least by default), so that may be why you’re getting different results on different machines.

Comment: I've been using dropbox to access the project on multiple machines (I am the sole developer), which I also discover doesn't store files with case sensitive file names, so the files I'm using in my dropbox folder on my new machine are project.xcdatamodeld and project.xcdatamodel as opposed to Project.xcdatamodeld and Project.xcdatamodel in my old machines dropbox folder. I'm going to call this 'case closed', thank you for your help. Do you have any recommendations for online storage of projects for access on multiple machines?

Comment: I think many people have successfully used Git with Dropbox as follows: store the project outside of your Dropbox folder and use Git to manage your commits. Then clone a bare repository into the Dropbox folder and to which you push/pull. Dropbox will then sync your repository and you can use Git to “sync” when you need to. It’s an additional level of indirection so it might not be your cup of tea.

Comment: You’re right, Dropbox does usually sync the correct filename case but won’t pick up renames if they only differ in case. The solution is to move the offending file out of your Dropbox folder, let Dropbox sync and then re-add it. Alternatively you could also try renaming the file once again (this time changing more than only the case) and then back to the correct filename.